# ICU Currency Locale Get Denomination

Tags: c++, currency, icu

Is there a way to probe an [ICU](http://icu-project.org/) Currency Locale for it's minimal denomination? For example US's would be $0.01, Korea (ko_KR) would be ₩1. I thought calling `getRoundingIncrement()` on the [`DecimalFormat` object](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html) may give it to me but that returns 0 for both en_US and ko_KR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look on: `getMinimumFractionDigits()` function:

```
#include <unicode/numfmt.h>
#include <unicode/ustream.h>
#include <unicode/ustring.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        UErrorCode e=U_ZERO_ERROR;
        icu::NumberFormat *fmt = icu::NumberFormat::createCurrencyInstance(e);
        std::cout << fmt->getMinimumFractionDigits() << std::endl;
        icu::UnicodeString str;
        std::cout << fmt->format(12345.5678,str) << std::endl;

        delete fmt;
}
```

This is the output of the program for different locales, seems it is what you need

```
$ ./a.out
2
$12,345.57
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 ./a.out
2
$12,345.57
$ LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF-8 ./a.out
0
￥12,346
$ LC_ALL=ko_KR.UTF-8 ./a.out
0
￦12,346
$ LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8 ./a.out
2
12 345,57 руб.
```

Comment: This is almost what I need. Some locales such as Switzerland (fr_CH) actually have nothing smaller than 0.05 and everything is in increments of 0.05 but the getMinimumFractionDigits() would still return 2.

Comment: @Travis also see getRoundingIncrement() and getRoundingMode() http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html#a2625aaab4e08c60f390f72ba3ef512a2

Comment: With these pieces I can infer the min denom. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Steve Loomis and Artyom for helping me piece together a solution.

```
double roundingIncrement = formatter->getRoundingIncrement();
int32_t minFractionDigits = formatter->getMinimumFractionDigits();
double minDenom;
if (roundingIncrement == 0.0 && minFractionDigits == 0.0)
{
 minDenom = 1.0;
}
else if (roundingIncrement != 0.0 && minFractionDigits > 0.0)
{
 minDenom = roundingIncrement;
}
else
{
 minDenom = 0.01;
}
```